# Exception when trying to read pack file with TextureAtlas

Tags: android, textures, libgdx

Shouldn't this work?

```
    TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("data/texture.png"));
    AtlasRegion region = atlas.findRegion("ape_glad");
    Sprite ape= new Sprite(region);
```

Instead I get: ***com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading pack file: data/texture.png*** at the first line above O.o

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to create a texture atlas, using [TexturePacker](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/TexturePacker) is the recommended way for libgdx. It results in the texture image and another file (containing the required information for libgdx `TextureAtlas`).

In your code, you need to provide the atlas file to the constructor, see [`TextureAtlas()` documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas.html#TextureAtlas%28com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle%29), instead of the image itself:

```
TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("data/texture.atlas"));
```

(Notice the use of the 'atlas'-file instead of the image file)

Comment: There is no such file as texture.pack, just texture.png.